Allowing other users to access web apps through browser on my PC with AWS Client VPN
For work, we do not have a dev environment and I run a lot of the applications I work on locally. We connect to our company cloud services via AWS Client VPN. I want to allow other devs to access the applications I run locally via their web browsers (the devops team at my previous job allowed this but it was not through AWS).
In AWS VPC, I was able to find (what I am pretty sure is) my IP address under VPC -> Client VPN Endpoints -> [selected VPC VPN endpoint] -> Connections, and then under the connections table, I see myself as connected. I then see a "Client IP" column, with an IP address.
When I try to connect as a test to an application I am running locally, I try using the client IP address from AWS above (example http://[ip-address-from-client-ip-column]:[port-number]/login. This does not work and the browser just spins for a while before displaying "This site cannot be reached". I would normally go through http://localhost:[port-number]/login, but if I wanted to share my work with someone in the same VPN as me to test I want to be able to give them my IP address so they can run the application I am running on my local environment.
Is this possible, and if so how do I go about doing this? Am I looking at the wrong IP address in AWS?
